# Windows phone 8 development & WebAPI - authenticating via forms auth?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an API with WebAPI that will accept authentication information over SSL via HTTPS from the web browser client.  The web browser uses forms authentication and requires HTTPS so it can securely sent username/password to the API endpoint.  My API uses Websecurity.Login() and Websecurity.Logout() to handle authentication for the web client.

How would this get handled in a WP8 application / Universal app built with WinJS?  Can I do the same thing - send login / registration credentials over HTTPS and use Websecurity to handle forms auth?

Here's how my WebAPI is currently set up for auth:

```
public HttpResponseMessage LogIn(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "already logged in.");
        }

        if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "logged in successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}

public HttpResponseMessage LogOut()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "logged out successfully.");
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "already done.");
}
```

Is this approach compatible with WP8 or other native mobile app development authentication?

Comment: "How would this get handled in a WP8 application / Universal app built with WinJS? Can I do the same thing - send login / registration credentials over HTTPS and use Websecurity to handle forms auth?" I think you would be fine, if you use form auth, you have to composite the request post and also handle the cookie returned from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would definitely work, assuming that consecutive requests carry the cookie that is appended to the very first request to the `Login` action.

In case of a browser app that uses ajax this works out of the box as consecutive ajax requests carry all cookies issued by the same domain and appended in the current browser session.

In case of a native application this could be tricker because it means that the same client proxy instance would have to be used or you find a way to have a temporary local storage for authentication cookies and append these cookies to every request.

However, there is a potential drawback of this request: you assume that the login method can use the login/password in an active scenario to produce forms cookie. And this isn't always as simple as that.

This is because your site can potentially be federated with an external identity provider (ADFS, Azure Active Directory, Google, Facebook, whatever) so that the actual authentication takes place in another website and your website only gets the response that conforms to the single sign on protocol used (OAuth2, WS-Federation).

In such case, there is really no easy way to use the pair login/password at the server side to get the identity of the user.

A workaround in such case, where the identity provider is unknown, is to host the webbrowser control (if possible) and let it perform the passive authentication scenario - which means that you navigate to the application page and let the web browser control automatically 302 to the login page, no matter how many redirects it takes. Then, user provides credentials at the provider page and the web browser redirects all the way back to your application and this is where you catch the identity at the server side, close the web browser control and somehow (depending on the actual web browser host) read the authentication cookie so that you can attach it to further requests.

Sounds tricky, but we have found some federation scenarios where actual SSO protocols between parties were not guaranteed and such simulation of the passive scenario from within the hosted web browser was the only reliable way.

Comment: If the native application will only ever accept standard username/password via a form (no third-party auth), do we have to worry about the drawback you mentioned?

Comment: Also - when a native app on WP8 (like facebook) accepts username/password to authenticate, are they most likely doing forms auth, or is there another mechanism that is more suitable for native mobile apps?

Comment: Facebook authenticates using the Username-Password flow of the OAuth2 protocol. OAuth2 has multiple flows that support different scenarios and the U-P is for active scenarios. If Facebook would be further federated, this would not work or would require a lot of custom work for them. If you don't plan any federated scenarios, the U-P of the OAuth2 is still a good choice if you want to host a custom Username/Password form. Read more on the flow for example here https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Note that the difference between OAuth2 and the approach you plan is that instead of a cookie, consecutive requests carry the oauth2 header issued by the identity provider.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  Since we already have Forms auth implemented for web clients, will this mean we have to have another AuthController just for mobile clients, or would you recommend staying the course without introducing OAuth?

Comment: OAuth2 could be an option for future. Implementing it correctly would keep you busy for few days or even weeks. Sure, there are benefits like opening yourself for easy integration with just anyone following the well-known specs but would it introduce any value to you? Answer that by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use WebApi via JS to do forms auth , this is how with CORS

decorate controller (if you need to use CORS) (think you may need a nuget package for this).

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Once your happy with credentials set cookie

```
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

This is the Ajax for the HTML page,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',

    url: 'http://' + api + '/?alloworigin=true',
    data: { Username: "test", Password: "test12" },
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var x = data;
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert( msg.responsetext);
    }
});
```

Then any auth, decorated controller can be accessed, the cookie is then sent with every request

```
[Authorize]
```

shout if you have any questions.

Microsoft_Press_eBook_Programming_Windows_8_Apps_HTML_CSS_JavaScript_2E_PDF.pdf

http://aka.ms/611111pdf has some details on passing XHR with WinJS